# How to prevent destruction of references to local variables in Rust?

Tags: memory, rust, scope

I have two structures. First is `Point` with two `i32` coordinates, second is a `Line` with references to two `Point`s. Structures have `new` and `random` constructors.

Required usage is:

```rust
use sandbox::{Point, Line};

fn main() {
    let line = Line::new(&Point::new(1, 2),
                         &Point::new(1, 2));
    line.from; // error[E0716]: temporary value dropped while borrowed
    Line::random(10, 10); // error[E0515]: cannot return value referencing local variable `a`
}
```

And structs:

```rust
use rand::Rng;

pub struct Point {
    pub x: i32,
    pub y: i32,
}

pub struct Line<'line> {
    pub from: &'line Point,
    pub to: &'line Point,
}

impl Point {
    pub fn new(x: i32, y: i32) -> Point {
        Point { x, y }
    }
    pub fn random(x_max: i32, y_max: i32) -> Point {
        let x = rand::thread_rng().gen_range(0..=x_max);
        let y = rand::thread_rng().gen_range(0..=y_max);
        return Point::new(x, y);
    }
}

impl<'line> Line<'line> {
    pub fn new<'a>(from: &'a Point, to: &'a Point) -> Line<'a> {
        Line { from, to }
    }
    pub fn random<'a>(img_width: i32, img_height: i32) -> Line<'a> {
        let a = Point::random(img_width, img_height);
        let b = Point::random(img_width, img_height);
        Line::new(&a, &b)
        // error[E0515]: cannot return value referencing local variable `a`
        // returns a value referencing data owned by the current function
    }
}
```

Two errors occur. The first is related to the fact that the `Point::new` passed to `Line` is destroyed after `Line::new` is executed, so further usage is impossible. It would be possible to take it out into separate variable, but this does not meet the requirements of the usage.

The second error is related to the fact that the generated `Point::random` needed to build `Line::random` is local, which means that after `Line::random` is executed, it also become inaccessible.

One possible solution is to use a heap(`Box<T>`), but I haven't been able to figure out how to avoid destruction after the function completes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your usage of references is misplaced here.

If `Line` *must* have references, I'd use a reference counted smartpointer instead.

The main problem is that if you store references in `Line`, `Line` does not **own** the `Point`s. That means, you have to keep them alive externally.

This is the reason why your `random` constructor fails:

```
pub fn random(x_max: i32, y_max: i32) -> Point {
    let x = rand::thread_rng().gen_range(0..=x_max);
    let y = rand::thread_rng().gen_range(0..=y_max);
    return Point::new(x, y);
}
```

As `Point::new` does not take ownership of `x` and `y`, the variables `x` and `y` cease to exist at the end of the `random` function.

---

### Solution

There are two ways to solve this:

- Use values instead of references (e.g. make `Point` cloneable)
- Use reference counting smart pointers

In your case, as `Point` is a very trivial type, I'd go with the first option:

```rust
use sandbox::{Line, Point};

fn main() {
    let line = Line::new(Point::new(1, 2), Point::new(1, 2));
    println!("{:?}", line);
    let line2 = Line::random(10, 10);
    println!("{:?}", line2);
}
```

```rust
use rand::Rng;

#[derive(Clone, Debug)]
pub struct Point {
    pub x: i32,
    pub y: i32,
}

#[derive(Clone, Debug)]
pub struct Line {
    pub from: Point,
    pub to: Point,
}

impl Point {
    pub fn new(x: i32, y: i32) -> Point {
        Point { x, y }
    }
    pub fn random(x_max: i32, y_max: i32) -> Point {
        let x = rand::thread_rng().gen_range(0..=x_max);
        let y = rand::thread_rng().gen_range(0..=y_max);
        return Point::new(x, y);
    }
}

impl Line {
    pub fn new(from: Point, to: Point) -> Line {
        Line { from, to }
    }
    pub fn random(img_width: i32, img_height: i32) -> Line {
        let a = Point::random(img_width, img_height);
        let b = Point::random(img_width, img_height);
        Line::new(a, b)
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Line { from: Point { x: 1, y: 2 }, to: Point { x: 1, y: 2 } }
Line { from: Point { x: 9, y: 1 }, to: Point { x: 9, y: 1 } }
```

---

### Solution #2 (with reference counters)

This solution is just for reference.

As previously mentioned, it is way overkill for simple data structures, which should rather derive the `Clone` trait.

If you are in a multi-threaded environment, replace `Rc<RefCell<Point>>` with `Arc<Mutex<Point>>`.

```rust
use std::{cell::RefCell, rc::Rc};

use sandbox::{Line, Point};

fn main() {
    let line = Line::new(
        Rc::new(RefCell::new(Point::new(1, 2))),
        Rc::new(RefCell::new(Point::new(1, 2))),
    );
    println!("{:?}", line);
    let line2 = Line::random(10, 10);
    println!("{:?}", line2);
}
```

```rust
use std::{cell::RefCell, rc::Rc};

use rand::Rng;

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Point {
    pub x: i32,
    pub y: i32,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Line {
    pub from: Rc<RefCell<Point>>,
    pub to: Rc<RefCell<Point>>,
}

impl Point {
    pub fn new(x: i32, y: i32) -> Point {
        Point { x, y }
    }
    pub fn random(x_max: i32, y_max: i32) -> Point {
        let x = rand::thread_rng().gen_range(0..=x_max);
        let y = rand::thread_rng().gen_range(0..=y_max);
        return Point::new(x, y);
    }
}

impl Line {
    pub fn new(from: Rc<RefCell<Point>>, to: Rc<RefCell<Point>>) -> Line {
        Line { from, to }
    }
    pub fn random(img_width: i32, img_height: i32) -> Line {
        let a = Rc::new(RefCell::new(Point::random(img_width, img_height)));
        let b = Rc::new(RefCell::new(Point::random(img_width, img_height)));
        Line::new(a, b)
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Line { from: RefCell { value: Point { x: 1, y: 2 } }, to: RefCell { value: Point { x: 1, y: 2 } } }
Line { from: RefCell { value: Point { x: 9, y: 1 } }, to: RefCell { value: Point { x: 4, y: 8 } } }
```

Comment: While you're at it, you might as well have `Point` derive `Copy`, which will make it easier to exchange points without the need to sprinkle `.clone()` everywhere.

Comment: @Jmb while you are right I'm not a big fan of implicit copies in general. I think keeping copies explicit is a good thing. But of course that's personal preference.

Answer (score 1):

Well, this looks like you need for the points to be sometimes referenced and sometimes owned. Rust provides [`Cow`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/enum.Cow.html#) which comes in handy for this cases:

```rust
use rand::Rng;
use std::borrow::Cow;

#[derive(Clone)]
pub struct Point {
    pub x: i32,
    pub y: i32,
}

pub struct Line<'line> {
    pub from: Cow<'line, Point>,
    pub to: Cow<'line, Point>,
}

impl Point {
    pub fn new(x: i32, y: i32) -> Point {
        Point { x, y }
    }
    pub fn random(x_max: i32, y_max: i32) -> Point {
        let x = rand::thread_rng().gen_range(0..=x_max);
        let y = rand::thread_rng().gen_range(0..=y_max);
        return Point::new(x, y);
    }
}

impl<'line> Line<'line> {
    pub fn new(from: &'line Point, to: &'line Point) -> Line<'line> {
        Line { from: Cow::Borrowed(from), to:  Cow::Borrowed(to)}
    }
    pub fn random(img_width: i32, img_height: i32) -> Line<'line> {
        let a = Point::random(img_width, img_height);
        let b = Point::random(img_width, img_height);
        Self {
            from: Cow::Owned(a),
            to: Cow::Owned(b)
        }
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=64fd5fcb726a53a8dbe4b22a7d882a3f)

> One possible solution is to use a heap(Box), but I haven't been able to figure out how to avoid destruction after the function completes.

It does not, `Box` are still constrain to rust borrowing rules, and unless you leak it (making the references `&'static`) will complain about the temporary values droped after the function scope.

About the `main`, you just need to bind the `Point`s to a variable, so they will live for the scope of `main`:

```rust
fn main() {
    let (from, to) = (Point::new(1, 2), Point::new(1, 2));
    let line = Line::new(&from, &to);
    line.from;
    Line::random(10, 10);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=f24e7d68c69ab2d84bfb30bc64f06ac9)

Comment: While your answer is correct, I feel that the question has rust-beginner vibes and `Cow` is way overkill for a problem that shouldn't have references in the first place. (Unless that's what OP actually wants, in which case your answer is of course relevant)

Comment: @Finomnis, yes, you may be right about the beginner vibes. Thanks for adding another answer which complete for the full range of solutions. At the end this is not just for the OP but for whoever finds himself here with a similar problem in the future. This way we keep all of them covered :D